# iphone software update failed

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'm trying to update my iphone in iTunes to the newest sw and it tries to download it and then I get the error "There was a problem downloading the software. You don't have enough access privileges for this operation."

I used to be able to do this on this iMac. 
Can you tell me what directory these go into so I can check the privileges on it? Or possibly did I close a port somehow when installing git, and how do I fix that?

I need the latest update so I can compile in Xcode to latest OS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tell me what directory these go into so I can check the privileges on it? 
By default these go to ~/Library/iTunes/iPhone Software Updates folder. Or manually download iPhone software from http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/041-0551.20110325.Aw2Dr/iPhone3,1_4.3.1_8G4_Restore.ipsw for iphone 4  or if you have iphone 3GS http://appldnld.apple.com/iPhone4/041-0549.20110325.ZxP8u/iPhone2,1_4.3.1_8G4_Restore.ipsw .. download this ipsw file anywhere on your MAC and then connect iphone , open itunes option+click on the Update would let you choose source for update and then you can point to ipsw you downloaded. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much. That's what I was missing :-)